# How to reject a pull request if target branch wasn't merged with source before hand?

Tags: merge, bitbucket-server

I have a release branch say release/steamboat. We have many feature branches (say feature/ui, feature/engine).

Lets say I want to auto-fail a pull request when it is created from feature/XX to release/steamboat if the requester didn't merge release/steamboat beforehand into feature/XX.

I am wondering if there is a way to tell the pull request creator that he/she needs to merge from latest release before creating it.

We are using Stash 3.11.3. We have a Bamboo based CI setup.

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to configure the merge option to fast forward only.

If the developer doesn't rebase his branch with the target branch, the merge will fail.

You can change this setting in the Stash config properties file:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/bitbucket-server-config-properties-776640155.html

[image]

You will have to restart the Stash service to take into account a change in this config file.

Comment: That is for the whole repo. Is there a way to do this for a specific branch?

Comment: I did a quick check with the existing plugins and I don't find a solution to do that for a specific branch.